# Fedora 29 - Switching to new user using "login" seems to fail

Tags: linux, fedora, users

I just installed Fedora 29 (Xfce edition). The user`vc` was created during installation. I created another user as `user2` (with the password: `u`) from the terminal but I am not able to log in with `user2`. The following is what I am doing:

```
[vc@localhost ~]$ sudo useradd user2
[sudo] password for vc:
[vc@localhost ~]$ sudo passwd user2
Changing password for user user2.
New password:
BAD PASSWORD: The password is a palindrome
Retype new password:
passwd: all authentication tokens updated successfully.
[vc@localhost ~]$ login user2
[vc@localhost ~]$ whoami
vc
[vc@localhost ~]$
```

I expected the `whoami` command to return `user2`.What am I missing?

Comment: What is the exit code of `login user2`? I think you have to be `root` to use `login`. You can also try `login` without username. This should prompt for a username.

Comment: `login` only works as root. And it's not how you switch users anyway. `su` is. What are you trying to do here?